# Return line number from string match

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the line number returned on a string search into a variable.

**Process**

1. run through filtered files in a directory
2. open each file and search for string
3. store line number with text match

I get the line number to return, but don't know how to work with it from here.

```
# Pull files from source directory with extension filter
Get-ChildItem $SourceDirectory -Filter $OutputFileExtension -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object {
        Select-String $_ -Pattern $TargetString |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'LineNumber'
    }
```

Comment: If you need the line numbers stored in a variable, just do it :) `$LineNumbers = Get-ChildItem ...`. What are you trying to accomplish? What will you use the line numbers for later?

Comment: What do you mean by "text match"? The entire line, or just the matching (sub)string? Also, store where and in which format? BTW, you don't need `ForEach-Object` here. `Select-String` can read directly from the pipeline.

Comment: Honestly, just get rid of `|Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'LineNumber'` and capture the resulting collection of [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo_members(v=vs.85).aspx) objects in a variable. That will store the info you want.

Comment: Thanks for getting back and the suggestions. They've helped much!  The goal is to: 1) find the line number that contains the $TargetString 2) delete all lines that are X number above and X number below the $TargetString line in the text file.

Answer (score 4):

Did a little more work on this. This functions for what I need. Improvements?

```
# Pull files from source directory with extension filter
Get-ChildItem $SourceDirectory -Filter $OutputFileExtension |


ForEach-Object {

    #Assign variable for total lines in file
    $measure = Get-Content $_.FullName | Measure-Object
    $TotalLinesInFile = $measure.count


    #Assign variable to the line number where $TargetString is found
    $LineNumber = Select-String $_ -Pattern $TargetString | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'LineNumber'
    Write-Host "Line where string is found: "$LineNumber

    #Store the line number where deletion begins
    $BeginDelete = $Linenumber - $LinesToDeleteBefore
    Write-Host "Line Begin Delete: "$BeginDelete

    #Store the line number where deletion ends
    $EndDelete = $LineNumber + $LinesToDeleteAfter 
    Write-Host "Line End Delete: "$EndDelete

    #Assign variable for export file
    $OutputFile = $ExportDirectory + $_.Name

    #Get file content for update
    $FileContent = Get-Content $_.FullName
    Write-Host "FileContent: " $FileContent

    #Remove unwanted lines by excluding them from the new file
    $NewFileContent = $FileContent[0..$BeginDelete] + $FileContent[($EndDelete + $LineToDeleteAfter)..$TotalLinesInFile] | Set-Content $OutputFile 


}
```